# How to test linearity in ordinal logistic regression analysis?

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data, diagnostic, linearity

One of the assumptions for performing ordinal regression is linearity. How to test this for this specific type of regression? Do you have to use logit etc.? And how does this work in SPSS?

Comment: Do you mean "linearity" in terms of the relationship between the log-odds of the outcome and its predictors, or the proportional odds (or parallel regression) assumption, which can be assessed [graphically](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/) or using dedicated test (e.g., [Brant test](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/dae/ordered-logistic-regression/))?

Comment: The first one, relationship between log-odds of the outcome and its predictors. I assume the latter is tested using the spss output of the ordinal regression analysis by looking at the test of parallel lines outcome?

Comment: The Brant test is anti-conservative.  See Peterson and Harrell (1990) and https://fharrell.com/post/rpo

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about ordinal regression models in this regard. You would assess linearity in the same manner as you would for a linear or binary logistic regression, comparing results for variables as they are vs. appropriate transformations of them and/or combinations of predictors. There's no automated way to formally test this in any of the SPSS regression procedures (or in those in other packages either, as far as I know).